# Access to Android Play API for subscriptions

Tags: android, api, google-play, in-app-subscription

Im trying to get information about subscriptions purchased through our Android application but keep getting this responso via this link

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/[package]/subscriptions/[product id]/purchases/[subscription id]?access_token=[access token]
```

I've have activate the API in the API console and created a web application client id

[image: client id from api console]

Then I've Allow and copied the given 'code' paramtere from this link

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&redirect_uri=http://localhost&client_id=[client id]
```

And getting the refresh token and access token (and in this storing the refresh token for later usage) via php from our server

Getting the refresh token
    $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

```
$post_fields = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => urldecode($code),
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
    "redirect_uri" => urldecode($redirect_uri));
```

Getting the access token

```
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

$post_fields = $fields = array(
    "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
    "refresh_token" => $refresh_token);
$content = get_content($url, $post_fields);
```

Both calls are done with as a POST request

```
function get_content($url, $post_fields) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
}
```

My question is why I'm still getting this response from Google

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "developerDoesNotOwnApplication",
    "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
 }
```

}

Comment: No - haven't looked a lot at this - updated to version 3 of the shop API and done a lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. From what I know I can say that this problem occurs when you generate a refresh_token from an account that doesn't own the application (is not the owner). So you have to do it from the owner account and it will work.